# Whats wrong with my Basil sapling?

Tags: diseases, basil

I live in Pune, India.
The weather these days is like Temp: 15 to 30 deg C, Humidity: 30 to 60%.
The sapling bought from a local nursery a month ago, the plant is kept in the shade. We water regularly, and There was no overuse of fertilizer or manure. The transplant was done by the gardener, so I think its safe to say that roots weren't damaged either.

What could be the issue? What do I do?

[image]

Comment: Possibly you water too much, and too much fertilizers. The plant is small, it does not need much stuffs (and if you have good soil/initial fertilizer, it will be enough until the plant really start to grow). The plant will appreciate some sun (but do not put it to noon sunlight until it is accustomed to sun.